# Docker dynamic configuration files

Tags: docker, configuration, docker-compose

Some of my Docker containers require configuration files (think: JSON, YAML or INI files) that depend on environment variables and/or container arguments.

What is the standard approach to automatically generate those environment files?

Solutions I have considered so far include:

1. [Tiller](https://github.com/markround/tiller): but I'm not excited by the idea of adding a ruby gem to my containers.
2. A custom string replacement script written in the same language as my other applications: but I don't want to include an extra script in all my docker projects.
3. `sed -i s/ENVVAR/${ENVVAR}/g config.json`: it works but it's a bit too "raw" for my taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd), highly recommend it for this particular use case of "I want templating with minimal clutter in my image". confd allows you to use a local environment variable backend to template out whatever config file format you want.

Comment: Almost two years later, the internet is full of utilities to render templated configuration files. I even created mine! https://pypi.org/project/ced/ There's no single solution, but instead a myriad of solutions for each programming and template language. Examples: https://github.com/wrouesnel/p2cli https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli
Just search for "docker render <template language> template in <programming language>".